# Animated PanResponder created with functional component jumps animation even though .setOffset() is implemented

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation

Ive seen a few questions about this topic but none have a solid answer.

I am basically re-writing an animated component which is written as a **class based component** into a **functional component**. The issue is that in my functional component the animation jumps every time decay is finished animating and the view is touched again. The solution for this is to set the offset of the animated view's x and y values to its own current x and y values. I am attempting to implement that same logic in the **functional component** but for some reason it does not work the same way as the class based component. Am I doing something wrong? Here are both components side by side. Again, the class based component works perfectly but the functional based component jumps every time the screen is touched after animation has been initiated.

**CLASS BASED COMPONENT**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Animated,
  PanResponder,
} from "react-native";

export default class animations extends Component {
  state = {
    animation: new Animated.ValueXY(0),
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this._x = 0;
    this._y = 0;

    this.state.animation.addListener(value => {
      this._x = value.x;
      this._y = value.y;
    });

    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: () => {
        this.state.animation.setOffset({ x: this._x, y: this._y });
        this.state.animation.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
      },
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
        null,
        { dx: this.state.animation.x, dy: this.state.animation.y },
      ]),
      onPanResponderRelease: (e, { vx, vy }) => {
        Animated.decay(this.state.animation, {
          velocity: { x: vx, y: vy },
          deceleration: 0.997,
        }).start();
      },
    });
  }

  render() {
    const animatedStyle = {
      transform: this.state.animation.getTranslateTransform(),
    };

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[styles.box, animatedStyle]}
          {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  box: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: "tomato",
  },
});
```

**FUNCTIONAL COMPONENT**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Animated, PanResponder } from 'react-native'


const Decays = (props) => {
    const AnimatedValue = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY(0)).current

    let _x = useRef(0).current
    let _y = useRef(0).current

    useEffect(() => {
        AnimatedValue.addListener((value) => {
            _x = value.x
            _y = value.y
        })
    })

    const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true, 
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true, 
        onPanResponderGrant: () => {
            AnimatedValue.setOffset({
                x: _x,
                y: _y,
            })
            AnimatedValue.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 })
        },
        onPanResponderMove: Animated.event(
            [
                null, 
                {
                    dx: AnimatedValue.x, 
                    dy: AnimatedValue.y,
                },
            ],
            { useNativeDriver: false }
        ),
        onPanResponderRelease: (e, { vx, vy }) => {
            Animated.decay(AnimatedValue, {
                velocity: { x: vx, y: vy },
                deceleration: 0.996,
                useNativeDriver: true,
            }).start()
        },
    })

    const animatedStyle = {
        transform: AnimatedValue.getTranslateTransform(),
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <Animated.View
                style={[styles.box, animatedStyle]}
                {...panResponder.panHandlers}
            ></Animated.View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    box: {
        backgroundColor: 'tomato',
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
})

export default Decays
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

Turns out my logic is not the issue. I have successfully converted the component from class based to function based. The jumping issue is caused by the useNativeDriver: true set on the decay animation. When this is set to false it does not jump.